# wsimport error file unreachable. But same file can be access through browser

Tags: wsimport

I am trying to run wsimport to parse some xsd file

wsimport  http://xxx.example.com:8080/schemas/enterprise/guid/xxx.xsd

it throw an error 
[ERROR] http://xxx.example.com:8080/schemas/enterprise/guid/xxx.xsd is unreachable

If I look at the file in any browser using the same http. I can see the file with no problem. So the file is on the server.

Do wsimport use some special proxy port different from brwoser?

Another interesting thing I notice the wsimport command will work if I have fiddler running. (Not an ideal solution since this is part of the ant build script)

I am thinking there some wsimport proxy issue. but Not sure how this can happen and how to check proxy setting.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Are you using *wsimport* from command line or from an IDE?

Comment: I changed xxx.com to example.com to removing link to inappropriate content.